# How to get "computed" text content of an HTML node (whitespace adjusted)

Tags: javascript, html, dom, browser, scripting

I want to be able to get the "computed" text content of an HTML node, i.e. as rendered by the browser.

**Example**: Consider the following html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <p>a
            b
            c          d
            e
            f &nbsp; g
            <div>1</div><div>2</div>
            <a>3</a><a>4</a>
            <button onclick="javascript:alert(document.body.textContent)">click 
me</button>
        </p>
        <pre>h            i</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here's a picture of how the above html renders in Chrome 41.0.2272.101 m on Windows 7:

[image]

Is there a simple, or relatively simple, way to approximate the text of the `<body>` node, for example, in a way that captures the fact that some html node boundaries essentially "generate" whitespace (like the boundary between the `<div>` nodes in the above example)?

I would like my approximation of the text of the `<body>` node to be a string something like:

```
a b c d e f   g

1
2
34 click me
h            i
```

Comment: Notice, that `p` can't contain `div`. Browser will close the paragraph before `div` starts when parsing the code, and the result will be different from the example. You can see it even in the posted image, there's a blank line (the bottom-margin of the `p`) before showing the content of the first `div`.

Comment: It may seem a bit crazy, but your best chance might be to use http://lynx.isc.org which is designed precisely to produce that sort of rendering, and it's not as easy as it might seem (you have to take CSS into account…).